# Searching in a ArrayList with custom objects for certain strings

Tags: java, search, arraylist, custom-object

I have a ArrayList with custom objects. I want to search inside this ArrayList for Strings.

The class for the objects look like this:

```
public class Datapoint implements Serializable {

  private String stateBased;
  private String name;
  private String priority;
  private String mainNumber;
  private String groupadress;
  private String dptID;

  public Datapoint(){
  }

  public String getMainNumber() {
    return mainNumber;
  }

  public void setMainNumber(String mainNumber) {
    this.mainNumber = mainNumber;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  ..and so on
```

I know how to search for a string in a ArrayList but how to do that in a ArrayList with my custom objects:

```
ArrayList<String> searchList = new ArrayList<String>();
String search = "a";
int searchListLength = searchList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
if (searchList.get(i).contains(search)) {
//Do whatever you want here
}
}
```

So I want to have a function to search in my ArrayList with for example five objects for all "name" strings.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The easy way is to make a `for` where you verify if the atrrtibute `name` of the custom object have the desired string

```
    for(Datapoint d : dataPointList){
        if(d.getName() != null && d.getName().contains(search))
           //something here
    }
```

I think this helps you.

Comment: also tried this one, but it does not find my String. If i convert my ArrayList to String it looks like this `[[[true] [Wippe links oben] [1] [1.001] [Low] [1 ]], [[true] [Wippe rechts] [1] [1.001] [Low] [2 ]], [[true] [Temperaturwert] [7] [7.001] [Low] [256 ]], [[true] [Schalten (Status)] [1] [1.001] [Low] [257 ]]]`

Comment: What is the String that you want to find in that example?

Comment: Ok. The code i posted only searchs for the name Attribute. You can add other verifications inside te IF clause. Like: `d.getMainNumber().contains...` This will solve the problem, but is not a beautifull solution. Will the attributes change in a future?

Comment: ah of course.... the attributes are always the same, so I will implement six if clauses and that should solve my problem. Do you know a better or more beautiful solution? How can I find out the attribute "Name" for my "MainNumber"?

Comment: You can implement a method inside the Datapoint class that do the verifications in all attributes. This way, you just call this method at the IF and it will return if the object has the desired string at one attribute or not. Other solution is to use Reflection and get all the methods, but i think this is over kill.

Answer (score 44):

UPDATE: Using Java 8 Syntax

```
List<DataPoint> myList = new ArrayList<>();
//Fill up myList with your Data Points

List<DataPoint> dataPointsCalledJohn = 
    myList
    .stream()
    .filter(p-> p.getName().equals(("john")))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If you don't mind using an external libaray - you can use [Predicates](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicates.html) from the [Google Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) as follows:

```
class DataPoint {
    String name;

    String getName() { return name; }
}

Predicate<DataPoint> nameEqualsTo(final String name) {
    return new Predicate<DataPoint>() {

        public boolean apply(DataPoint dataPoint) {
            return dataPoint.getName().equals(name);
        }
    };
}

public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<DataPoint> myList = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
    //Fill up myList with your Data Points

    Collection<DataPoint> dataPointsCalledJohn =
            Collections2.filter(myList, nameEqualsTo("john"));

}
```

Comment: Finally java 8 got functional notation. Rulz!

Comment: I need a similar solution for Java 7 because Android sucks on Java 8 on lower APIs

Comment: is there is a difference in performance with this answer and the upper one?

Answer (score 8):

try this

```
ArrayList<Datapoint > searchList = new ArrayList<Datapoint >();
String search = "a";
int searchListLength = searchList.size();
for (int i = 0; i < searchListLength; i++) {
if (searchList.get(i).getName().contains(search)) {
//Do whatever you want here
}
}
```

Comment: Possible NullPointerException if getName() is not set up.

Comment: just thinking that each and every value for the particular object are set.

Comment: If i convert my ArrayList to String it looks like this `[[[true] [Wippe links oben] [1] [1.001] [Low] [1 ]], [[true] [Wippe rechts] [1] [1.001] [Low] [2 ]], [[true] [Temperaturwert] [7] [7.001] [Low] [256 ]], [[true] [Schalten (Status)] [1] [1.001] [Low] [257 ]]]` . If I use for example `String search = "1.001";` it does not find any string... do you have a idea? –

Comment: why are you converting it to a string? Are you interested to find whether the string search is in your arraylist irrespective of whether it is in stateBased or name or priority or mainNumber or   groupadress or dptID?

Answer (score 5):

Probably something like:

```
ArrayList<DataPoint> myList = new ArrayList<DataPoint>();
//Fill up myList with your Data Points

//Traversal
for(DataPoint myPoint : myList) {
    if(myPoint.getName() != null && myPoint.getName().equals("Michael Hoffmann")) {
        //Process data do whatever you want
        System.out.println("Found it!");
     }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

For a custom class to work properly in collections you'll have to implement/override the `equals()` methods of the class. For sorting also override `compareTo()`.

See [this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=17) or google about how to implement those methods properly.

Answer (score 3):

`contains()` method just calls `equals()` on `ArrayList` elements, so you can overload your class's `equals()` based on the `name` class variable. Return `true` from `equals()` if `name` is equal to the matching `String`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Doesn't this prevent him from searching on other fields?

Comment: @gtgaxiola, It does, and it's also not a good decision design-wise, but it's usually not good to compare different data types.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Apache CollectionUtils`:

```
CollectionUtils.find(myList, new Predicate() {
   public boolean evaluate(Object o) {
      return name.equals(((MyClass) o).getName());
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String string;
for (Datapoint d : dataPointList) {    
   Field[] fields = d.getFields();
   for (Field f : fields) {
      String value = (String) g.get(d);
      if (value.equals(string)) {
         //Do your stuff
      }    
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean found;

for(CustomObject obj : ArrayOfCustObj) {

   if(obj.getName.equals("Android")) {

      found = true;
   }
}
```