# How to search list of objects of java using a property name

Tags: java, list, search, dictionary, arraylist

I have a map like as follows

```
Map<String,Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

map.put("one",1);
map.put("two",2);
```

If i want to get an element from map i can use

```
 map.get("one");
```

I have a list

```
List<TestVO> list = new ArrayList<TestVO>();
TestVO vo1 = new TestVO();
  vo1.setId(1);
  vo1.setName("one");


TestVO vo2 = new TestVO();
  vo2.setId(2);
  vo2.setName("two");

list.add(vo1);
 list.add(vo2);
```

If i want to search from this list which has name "one" i need to iterate this list.Is there any simple way to find out this?

I found this [Searching in a ArrayList with custom objects for certain strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496038/searching-in-a-arraylist-with-custom-objects-for-certain-strings)

But is there any other simple way to do that?Thanks in advance...

Comment: have you tried using `Collections.binarySearch(list, "one");`?

Comment: @Linus "one" is a name property of TestVO class. Instances of TestVO are stored in the List.

Comment: Did you read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12496479/2024761) in the question you linked?

Comment: @R.J I saw the marked answer

Comment: Marked answer doesn't mean that's the best answer. It means that the marked answer helped OP solve their problem, but doesn't mean other answers are wrong. If you'd read the other answers, you'd have seen it and if you're not bound by any clause to not use a 3rd-party lib, then the answer I proposed could very well be your solution. Why not give it a try?

Comment: In my first comment, I linked that answer. "this answer" in my first comment, is a link.

Answer (score 3):

**Searching data in Hash Map is of complexity O(1) where as in case of List it is O(N).**

So unfortunately the answer is you have to iterate over the list. That is why choosing proper data structure is so important.

Comment: @Debriter I meant HashMap if that is what your point is. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553624/hashmap-get-put-complexity