# Scrolltoposition/ smoothscrolltoposition for recyclerview under a nestedscrollview layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a recyclerview under a nestedsrcollview. I want to implement the scrolling to a specific position for the recyclerview but I am having difficulty with it. The xml code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".HomeFragment"
    android:background="#ffffff"

    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:id="@+id/nestedscrollview"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

       <<some other layouts>>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/home_blog_list"

            android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"

            />





    </LinearLayout>




</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I want to implement the scrolltoposition for the home_blog_list recyclerview to a position (say 26). How to do it? P.S.- I have set nestedscrollingenabled to false for the home_blog_list.Please note that I want to scroll the nestedscrollview to a specific row of the recyclerview. I dont want the case where the recyclerview is scrolled only. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recycler view scroll to specific position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43829419/recycler-view-scroll-to-specific-position)

Comment: No it didnt work. I actually am scrolling the nestedscrollview. The recyclerview is inside that. How to scroll the nestedscrollview to a specific position of recyclerview inside it?

Comment: why you need nested scrollview. recyclerview is aleady scrolable.it will cause many problems while scrolling if you implement nested scrollview and recyclerview altogether.

Comment: Actually I have one other recyclerview (this one is horizontal) in my layout. And I wanted the whole system to scroll. (Just like the status recyclerview and the posts recyclerview in instagram).

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled into the same issue and I found an easy solution that does not require to refactor by using the library suggested by asif-ali.

On my current project, I have a `NestedScrollView` that holds a `ConstraintLayout`.
This `ConstraintLayout` contains a complex header made of multiple view, and then my `RecyclerView`.

**Much like you, I needed the whole thing to be scrollable.**

That said, when the user wishes to see an item from the particular `RecyclerView`, you would normally call:

> RecyclerView#smoothScrollToPosition(int position)

But since the `RecyclerView`'s height is set to `wrap_content` the full list is displayed, with as many `ViewHolder`s as there are items in its `adapter`.
Granted, we do not benefit from recycling, but then why would we need a `ScrollView` ? Using @asif-ali solution might surely bring recycling optimizations but that's not the point here.

So, we have a fully laid-out `RecyclerView`. In order to scroll to a particular item (`ViewHolder#itemView`) position, you can do as followed:

```
final void smoothScrollToPosition(final int position) {
    final ViewHolder itemViewHolder = this.recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    // at this point, the ViewHolder should NOT be null ! Or else, position is incorrect !

    final int scrollYTo = (int) itemViewHolder.itemView.getY();
    // FYI: in case of a horizontal scrollview, you may use getX();
    this.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
        0, // x - for horizontal
        scrollYTo
    );
}
```

That's it !
It might be possible child is not fully visible after doing so (in my test case) so I'd suggest to add half the height of the itemView to the `scrollYTo` variable to make sure the `nestedScrollView` will scroll enough. If you do so, you might also want to check out in which direction the `nestedScrollView` must scroll to (either up, then remove half height, or down, then add half height.

---

### [EDIT 1]

After further testing and research, based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6831790/3535408 it is actually better and simpler to target the `itemView.getBottom`. On my app, it works flawlessly.

So the updated code looks as followed:

```
final void smoothScrollToPosition(final int position) {
    final ViewHolder itemViewHolder = this.recyclerView.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(position);
    // at this point, the ViewHolder should NOT be null ! Or else, position is incorrect !

    // FYI: in case of a horizontal scrollview, you may use getX();
    this.nestedScrollView.smoothScrollTo(
        0, // x - for horizontal
        itemViewHolder.itemView.getBottom()
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want, have a look: [link](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

Comment: Providing link is ok. But try to add a bit information about your answer , it will improve your answer. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)