# Return string from arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Lets say I have a class

```
public class Ttype{
    
    private String type = "";

    public Ttype(String type) {
        
        this.type = type;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

and I have arraylist of this class

```
ArrayList<Ttype> type = new ArrayList<Ttype>();
```

I have added some elements to the arraylist

```
type.add( new new Ttype("Hello"));
type.add( new new Ttype("Bye"));
type.add( new new Ttype("Hi"));
```

I want to be able to return a string when I search for specefic string in the arraylist. What I mean by that is:

```
Ttype t = type.get("Hello"); //t will be set to "hello" if hello is in the arraylist.
```

How can I do that?

Comment: could it be, that you are looking for a map instead of an arraylist? `map.put("hello", new Ttype("Hello"));` and `map.get("Hello") //returns a object of type Ttype`

Comment: I have never actually heard of map before. I had enums before with different elements in it. Public Types Enum{ Hi, Hello, Bye}. Before I had like this Types t = Types.Bye; and then they can t value whenever then want eg. if( t != types.bye) t = types.hello; I want to do something similar but with arraylist. Like instead I have arraylist<Types> type = new Arraylist<Types>(); . I want to change my whole enum structur with arraylist instead. So Ttypes t = type.get("bye") and so on. I do not know if I am thinking wrong or if is it a way to go.

Comment: Simple: java collections have lists, sets, and maps. And you better learn what these are about. Jarlik is fully correct. You want to use a simple map for this task.

Comment: I recommend this [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Searching in a ArrayList with custom objects for certain strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12496038/searching-in-a-arraylist-with-custom-objects-for-certain-strings) Did you try searching the Internet for the words ___java search arraylist___ before posting your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
type.stream()
  .filter(c -> c.getType().equals("test"))
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: [Is it my duty to check for duplicate questions before answering?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326622/is-it-my-duty-to-check-for-duplicate-questions-before-answering)

Answer (score 0):

Well as others suggested in comments this will be much easy when you use a Map rather than ArrayList. But in your case to achieve what you need you can follow the below steps.This will be much easy when you use streams in Java 8.But I will provide a simple solution which you can achieve without streams.

```
Ttype result = null;//To store if an object found 
String searchTxt = "Hello";

for(Ttype temp:type){//Iterating through the list find a match

   if(temp.type.equlas(searchTxt)){
       result = temp;
   }

}
```

Now based on the value which contains in the result you can continue your work.If result is null after the iteration it means there is no matching item found.